# Win10 Computer Suddenly Thinks it is Win 8

Tags: windows-10

I am unable to boot into my laptop beyond safe mode. When attempting to boot, I get a BSOD with an error pointing to the module *fltmgr.sys (FLTMGR!FltpvPrintErrors+0x170)*

I also noticed Windows 10 was not my default OS anymore.
This is NOT a dual boot system:

[image]

Going into msconfig > boot, Windows 10 isn't even listed; just Windows 8, although when I go to Tools > About Windows, it does show me Windows 10:

(Again, this is not a dual boot system)
[image]

---

I am at a loss as to what to do at this point. The only thing I can think of is that this laptop came with Windows 8 before I updated it to Windows 10 and maybe something got reverted on accident. But I have no idea how to verify that. Could this be related to the BSOD error?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.  The only way Windows 8 would have reverted to Windows 10 is if you recently performed the upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: Please [edit] the post and improve your formatting. I've attempted to do it for you, but I'm unable to. I can't distinguish which parts are program output and which are your comments. Use lists, quotes, code blocks. [Formatting guide](https://superuser.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 10 several years ago. The only recent change was the failed Windows Update.

Comment: The program outputs are now in italics.

Comment: Those Winver Windows say it is Windows 10. Where *exactly* are you seeing it say Windows 8? Is it just during one of the boot device selection screens?

Comment: Yes, during boot device selections, when I type bcdedit into the cmd prompt, and in msconfig. All these say Windows 8 is my default, but it isn't, and I haven't been able to log in beyond safe mode since this happened. It did say Windows 10 at one point before I started getting BSOD.

Comment: So there is no way your Windows 10 machine is Windows 8 now.  It's literally impossible, so Windows 8 is listed, is just an artifact.  Your installation HAS NOT been reverted back to Windows 10.  It sounds like you should rebuild the boot configuration data.  You should backup your current boot configuration before you do that.

Comment: I've gone and rebuilt my boot configuration as best as I could, still says Windows 8. I'm still getting the same BSOD (with the fltmgr.sys module) when I try to boot into my system. I was asking about the Windows 8 thing to see if that had something to do with the crashes.

Comment: I just want to point out, the description likely always was set to Windows 8, since that you were running before you upgrade to Windows 10.  The description being incorrect is not the source of your problem.  As for your problem, when you indicated that "I am unable to boot into my laptop beyond safe mode.", do you mean you can boot into safe mode or do you mean something else?  Edit your question and clarify this point.  It appears you created the screenshots from the problem system, but it being the system in question, makes several possible solutions invalid so just checking.

Answer (score 1):

> I am unable to boot into my laptop beyond safe mode. When attempting to boot, I get a BSOD with an error pointing to the module fltmgr.sys (FLTMGR!FltpvPrintErrors+0x170)

A Blue Screen of Death, which indicates `fltmgr.sys` is the cause of the crash, most often is related to memory issues.

> I also noticed Windows 10 was not my default OS anymore.

Based on the information you provided, the default OS is set to your Windows 10 installation.  Windows 10 is the only Windows installation that is actually listed.  While the description, is set to Windows 8, the description was never updated when you upgraded to Windows 10.

This means it's always been set to Windows 8, and you wouldn't have ever noticed this unless you specifically went hunting for it.  **There is absolutely no way**, Windows 10 was downgraded to Windows 10, so the description simply being incorrect is the only explanation.

> Going into msconfig > boot, Windows 10 isn't even listed; just Windows 8,

As I already indicated.  Your Windows 10 installation actually is listed.  The description of the only Windows installation is simply incorrect.  The Windows Boot Manager only lists a single installation and the object it points to is your Windows 10 installation.

> I was asking about the Windows 8 thing to see if that had something to do with the crashes.

It absolutely is not linked to your crashes.

Comment: The incorrect description should be ignored.  If after, and only after you solve your actual problem, how you change the description would be a different question altogether.